# C++, searching an APT_String and efficiency

Tags: c++, datastage

To begin with, the solution to this question needs to be very efficient.

My problem is that I need to compare certain parts of two `APT_String`s (a DataStage type). Namely, the strings are surnames that contain a space char, such as "Brown Marrow". However, the names are in a 30 byte field, with the remaining space filled with space chars.

To put it short, I need to find the first instance of two consecutive space chars (to signal the end of the useful surname). My solution is

`bool foundit = false;`

`for (int ind = 0; ind<=q_array[i].LAST_NAME.length() && !foundit; ind++) {`
`if (q_array[i].LAST_NAME[ind] == ' ' && q_array[i].LAST_NAME[ind+1] == ' ') {`
`cout<<"two spaces in a row at char " << ind << endl;`

`foundit = true;`

`}`
`}`

Unfortunately, APT_String doesn't appear to have a find(), or I would use that. Does anyone have a better or more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Again, if you want to know if certain characters are in a string, you need to iterate over it. No other chance, Even `find` and `strcmp` and whatelse does this. No chance around this loop stuff.

Now, you can always wrap that `APT_String` in your own `myAPT_String` class which also has a `size_t string_size` member, which you need to manage, and use that to jump to the end of the string.

Comment: The efficiency part of the question assumes that find is a very refined method, seeing that it is included in C++'s string class. I know that it will iterate over the string, but I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do this than what I have done. And why do you say "again"? You act as if I have asked this question before...

Comment: @autotravis - You are not the only one asking questions here. :-) There is no magic available for seeing what is in a string without looking at the individual characters. The std::string has about a hundred functions too many, so that is not a good model.

Comment: @auto: The question about knowing where is what in a string is asked way too often. ;)

Comment: @Bo: Okay, well I apologize for this question seeming similar to others. It's all fine and dandy when a string can be searched by built-in methods of its class (which I wrongly assumed are adequately vetted in most languages). I just wanted to make sure my home-grown solution was as efficient as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

A 30 byte field cannot take long to scan, can it?

If looking for the end of the name, I would start at the end of the string and scan in reverse until the first non-space.